# check if getelementsbyclassname exists in excel vba. runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

All I am trying to pull data from a web page. 
I am looping through div with a class name from the webpage.  Sometimes specific elements inside the div does not exist. that time it's showing an error 
**runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set**
my VBA code is as below

```js
  m = 0
  For Each htmlele1 In doc.getElementsByClassName("results")
  m = m + 1

  companyname = htmlele1.getElementsByTagName("h2")
  Address = htmlele1.getElementsByTagName("span")
   
  If Address.getAttribute("itemprop") = "Address" Then
 
   Cells(i, (m * 4 + 2)).Value = companyname.innerText + "," + Address.innerText
  End If
  
  Teliphone = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("nolink")
  
  
  If Teliphone.getAttribute("itemprop") = "telephone" Then
  
  Cells(i, (m * 4 + 3)).Value = Teliphone.innerText

  End If
  

  no_of_property = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("agents-stats-l")

  
If InStr(no_of_property.innerText, "Residential for sale") <> 0 Then
             Cells(i, (m * 4 + 4)).Value = Replace(no_of_property.innerText, "Residential for sale:", "")
                Else
                 Cells(i, (m * 4 + 4)).Value = 0
            End If
            Sale_price = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("agents-stats-c")
             If InStr(Sale_price.innerText, "Avg. asking price") <> 0 Then
              Cells(i, (m * 4 + 5)).Value = Replace(Sale_price.innerText, "Avg. asking price: ", "")
              Else
                 Cells(i, (m * 4 + 5)).Value = 0
              End If

  Next
```

on above code snippet sometimes
** Teliphone = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("nolink")** This is  with snolink class and this  doesnot exists some time  and it shows error on next line.
How can I check whether element with class exists and overcome **"runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set"** this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the object beforehand and check if exists before attempting to access its properties.

```
Set objCollection = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("nolink")

If Not objCollection Is Nothing Then
    For Each objTeliphone In objCollection 
        'Access objTeliphone properties here
    Next
End If
```